# disable friendly_id for simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, friendly-id

I want to use `id` in my `simple_form` inside my admin dashboard

```
<%= simple_form_for ['admin', travel_insurance_product] do |f| %>
```

Currently the form use the `slug`.

How I can do that?

Comment: Can I ask why? The form would do the same thing if you use ID or the slug?

Comment: ^^ What he said. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me -- are you, for example, having difficulty writing the controller or integration tests?

Comment: @Vucko, its for the sake of consistency, I am using the iD as its reference in the admin side.